# References for mathematics enthusiasts?

Tags: reference-request

I'm willing to give a mathematics Olympiad [[syllabus]](http://www.rajrmo.com/downloads/suggest_rmo.pdf) and I can't buy all the book(or even some of them) and am looking for some online resources like questions, articles, or more prefably some single book with all topics(least probable).Or I would be pleased even if someone suggested some places to look upon for high level of questions for practice, note that you needn't mention this olympiad's(IMO's) previous questions as I would be doing them either way.

Comment: Do you know about the extensive web site [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/)?

Comment: I saw it, I only saw some books selling on the site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to look at the Art of Problem Solving website [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php). It has tons of problems with discussions, a lot of materials on different topics et.c.

There is a [very nice book](http://students.imsa.edu/~tliu/Math/planegeo.pdf) by Prasolov with problems in geometry which I would also recommend. It has a gigantic collection of problems, and a lot of them are pretty complicated.

I hope this helps a bit.